# Factorize integer larger than 200 digits c++

Tags: c++, factorization

I have to factorize a number given by text in C++, this number is greater than a double, and I can't use external libraries. I know this number is a product of the first 25 prime numbers. Is there a way I can process this number and give it's descomposition in prime? 
Whats the best algorithim I could use to do so?

Comment: If you know it's the product of the first 25 prime numbers, why do you need to factor it? Just use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to generate the first 25 primes.

Comment: @Barmar I think op meant the factors are from the 1st 25 prime numbers and they can be repeated.

Comment: I need to know of how many of this primes it is composed. I don't know how to explain it properly in english but for example if the number is 2^a * 3^ b i need to know a and b

Comment: You can try to implement the "paper and pencil" method. kind of annoying but not too complicated

Comment: The number is given as decimal digits?  Then there are easy tests for multiples of 2 and 5 (based on the last digits) and 3 and 9 (based on recursive sum of digits, of course 9 is not prime, but if you can find two 3s for the price of one, why not?)

Comment: Well the hard part is that I can't compare or divide the number because I can't contain it in a double or a float because of how big is it. Is there any way to implement it with the variable being in an array of chars?

Comment: It is given in decimal numbers, but I also have to get the exact number of.factors.

Comment: there should be plenty of bignum (arbitrary precision arithmetic) libraries for c++

Comment: The "I can't use external libraries" means that you are supposed to implement arbitrary precision integers. That's what the task is about. However, the question of how does one do that is too broad, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Just implement [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) then